# How to add navigation menu for interactive report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created an interactive report without choosing a new navigation menu option. Now I want to add a new navigation menu on the left side for my interactive report which I have created. How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The navigation menu is just a list. You can go to "Shared Components" > "Lists", and open it there. Alternatively, it will be visible from the page builder. In the page builder for that page, in the left pane, the far right tab says "Page Shared Components". The navigation is under "Lists" > "Page Navigation". That will open the list region for that page. Click the ">" icon next to "Source" to edit the list.